# How to declarate such number in java?

Tags: java

I've an array, which contains such numbers, like 0221, 0223, etc. What type of data I can use there? If I try to use long or int, it shows that after every number first 0 need to write comma. Array looks like there:

```
TYPE? isAvailable[] = {0221, 0223};
```

Comment: Why do you need the padding zero? Use a String if you need that exact notation. By the way, the zero indicates octal notation.

Comment: It is possible that what is ***actually*** needed here is [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) used with an `int[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want without comma but with leading zero and you want to store it as such in the array, I think you can only use `string` . If you don't mind about storing the leading zero, and the format is always 4 characters, you can use `int` and when showing the numbers, format them accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Use String .

```
String isAvailable[] = {"0221", "0223"};
```